# Why are generalized inequalities defined over proper cone?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis, dual-cone

Why generalized inequality is defined over a proper cone? What property does not hold if we define it over non-convex cone?  Same with `pointed'.  For example, generalized inequality makes sense in a cone defined as the 1st and third orthant, which is neither convex nor pointed.

Comment: What do you mean by "proper"?  Why do you say that we get a sensible generalized inequality if we use a cone defined as the union of the positive   and negative orthants?

Comment: here, http://www.princeton.edu/~chiangm/ele539l15.pdf